# MySQL - GROUP BY, JSON, LIMIT 5, etc

Tags: javascript, mysql

I have a table, called `feedback`, that contains: `no`, `date`, `id`, `message`, `value`.

- `no` The row number.
- `id` The employee id.
- `message` Feedback from a customer.
- `value` The feedback type. -1, 0, or 1.

Now I have a view which provides me with `id`, `messages`, `total`, `value`.

- `id` The employee id.
- `messages` An array of `message` which share `id` and `value`.
- `total` The total number of rows which share `id` and `value`.

```
CREATE 
    ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED 
    DEFINER = `root`@`localhost` 
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
VIEW `vw_feedback` AS
    SELECT 
        `feedback`.`no` AS `no`,
        `feedback`.`id` AS `id`,
        JSON_ARRAYAGG(`feedback`.`message`) AS `messages`,
        `feedback`.`value` AS `value`,
        COUNT(0) AS `total`
    FROM
        `feedback`
    GROUP BY `feedback`.`id` , `feedback`.`value`
    ORDER BY `feedback`.`date` DESC
```

What I would *like* to do, is instead have `id`, `negative_messages`, `positive_messages`, `total_negative`, `total_positive`, `total`.

- `id` The employee id.
- `negative_messages` An array of the **last 5** `message` for that `id` which have a `value` < 0.
- `positive_messages` An array of the **last 5** `message` for that `id` which have a `value` > 0.
- `total_negative` Total number of rows for that `id` with `value` < 0.
- etc...

I could use help on where to begin.

Comment: I don't know how well it applies to `JSON_ARRAYAGG`, but see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129693/mysql-using-limit-within-group-by-to-get-n-results-per-group for how to get 5 results per group.

Comment: Doesn't this view give you `GROUP BY` errors given that you're running MySQL 8?

Comment: @Nick- It does not. Should it? I'm not very good with MySQL. Even with Barmar's response I'm scratching my head.